# Can scripts be run directly from the ~/.config/autostart folder?

Tags: scripts, autostart

I've got a script file in my home directory that I've added to `Startup Applications`. It then creates a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart`. Is it possible to just cut out the middle man, and run this script directly from the autostart folder?

The structure of the script is along the lines of:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

I tried making it one line by rearranging the script to read:

```
command1;command2;command3
```

The idea behind this was to swap out the following line in the `.desktop` file from this:

```
Exec=/home/hiigaran/startupfile
```

To this:

```
Exec=command1;command2;command3
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing multiple commands aren't supported. Is there any other way?

To be clear, I don't have any particular problem with the current way I'm doing things. Everything functions as it should. I'm just very particular about my home directory contents. If there is a more elegant way to run my script after logging in to the desktop, great. If not, no big deal.

To my understanding, KDE has a ~/.config/autostart-scripts directory that would work perfectly for me. This seems to be a folder found only in KDE however. I'm using the default DE for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Read [official Desktop Entry Specification specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) and consider by yourself what will work and what will not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Exec=command1;command2;command3` try

```
Exec=sh -c "command1;command2;command3"
```

Comment: Initially, this one didn't work, but @N0rbert's link mentioned that I needed to escape some characters first. Works as intended now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against this sort of thing as you end up forgetting why you jumped through hoops you didn't need to.

Simply create a shell script containing your multiple commands and stick that in whatever local "bin" you use (typically `~/bin`) `chmod 755` it and reference THAT in your `.desktop` file.

It will, of course, be properly laid out, commented and maybe even be in your bin git repo ;)